# Xcode 10 - let code wait for finished animations

Tags: xcode, animation

I have a fade sequence of a fade in followed by a fade out. However, the execution of code does not wait until a single fade animation (fadeIn, fadeOut) is finished. How to fire fadeOut after fadeIn has finished?

Here is my basic code so far:

```
 func fadeIn(){
    if self.alpha == 0.0 {
    UIViewPropertyAnimator.runningPropertyAnimator(
        withDuration: 3.0,
        delay: 2.0,
        options:[.curveLinear],
        animations: {self.alpha = 1.0},
        completion: {if $0 == .end{print("FadeIn finished now")}})
    }

}


func fadeOut(){
    if self.alpha == 1.0 {
        UIViewPropertyAnimator.runningPropertyAnimator(
            withDuration: 3.0,
            delay: 2.0,
            options:[.curveLinear],
            animations: {self.alpha = 0},
            completion: {if $0 == .end{print("FadeOut finished now")}})
    }

}

//connect single Fades
func fadeSequence(){
   self.fadeIn()
    self.fadeOut()
}
```

The question is how to chain these animations one after the other, before further code is executed.

In my application I want to achieve a repeated loop, where each animation has to be finished before showing the next one:

```
for item in 0..<4{
print("runthrough:\(item)")

myView.fadeSequence()

}
```

My basic problem is the understanding of the completion part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're asking two questions here:

1. How do you call `fadeOut`, *after* `fadeIn` has finished?
2. How do you wait until `fadeSequence` has finished, before calling it again?

---

#### Question #1

If you always want to call `fadeOut` directly after running `fadeIn`, you can just do this:

```
func fadeIn(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    guard alpha == 0 else { return }
    UIViewPropertyAnimator.runningPropertyAnimator(
        withDuration: 3.0, delay: 2.0, options:[.curveLinear],
        animations: {
            self.alpha = 1.0
        },
        completion: { 
            self.fadeOut() 
        }
    )
}
```

Then, `fadeSequence` would only call `fadeIn()`.

You could, however, change the logic to handle the completion inside `fadeSequence`, which is a little more versatile, because then you can call `fadeOut` independently:

```
func fadeIn(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    guard alpha == 0 else { return }
    UIViewPropertyAnimator.runningPropertyAnimator(
        withDuration: 3.0, delay: 2.0, options:[.curveLinear],
        animations: {
            self.alpha = 1.0
        },
        completion: completion
    )
}

func fadeSequence() {
    fadeIn(completion: fadeOut)
}
```

---

#### Question #2

Add a completion handler to `fadeSequence` and then call it recursively. This also requires `fadeOut` to implement a completion handler, just like we added it to `fadeIn`.

```
func fadeSequence(numberOfCalls n: Int) {
    guard n > 0 else { return }
    fadeIn {
        self.fadeOut {
            fadeSequence(numberOfCalls: n-1)
        }
    }
}
```

---

Full code:

```
func fadeIn(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    guard alpha == 0 else { return completion() }
    UIViewPropertyAnimator.runningPropertyAnimator(
        withDuration: 3.0, delay: 2.0, options:[.curveLinear],
        animations: {
            self.alpha = 1
        },
        completion: completion
    )
}

func fadeOut(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    guard alpha == 1 else { return completion() }
    UIViewPropertyAnimator.runningPropertyAnimator(
        withDuration: 3.0, delay: 2.0, options:[.curveLinear],
        animations: {
            self.alpha = 0
        },
        completion: completion
    )
}

func fadeSequence(repeat n: Int = 1) {
    guard n > 0 else { return }
    fadeIn {
        self.fadeOut {
            fadeSequence(repeat: n-1)
        }
    }
}

someView.fadeSequence(repeat: 3)
```

Comment: Heres some errors when I try your code : "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments" in line 2 of Question#2

Comment: Have you implemented the completion handlers as parameters in the `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` methods?

Comment: just brought your code in to wrap my head around.  For me Its hard to determine which is generic and which is ready to go code. COmpletion handlers is some weird stuff.

Comment: Okay, so do `func fadeIn(completion: () -> Void) {` and `func fadeOut(completion: () -> Void) {`. Then that should be fixed.

Comment: completion: completion gives an error: Passing non-escaping parameter 'completion' to function expecting an @escaping closure

Comment: Just press the fix-it. I'm not on my Mac right now, so I can't test (and wasn't when writing this answer)

Comment: okay. what to do with the expected code in the call:  blueFadeView.fadeSequence {
                <#code#>
            }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194456/discussion-between-linusgeffarth-and-hiduei).

Comment: THX to Linus, checking the completion thing out.